# d3 pan/zoom with DOM center point is off

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to zoom and pan using d3.

I took an example from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e3925cdc804db257a86fdef3a032a45) and switched out the svg for regular dom.

**Code:**

```
var section = d3.select("section"),
    width = +section.attr("width"),
    height = +section.attr("height");

var points = d3.range(2000).map(phyllotaxis(10));

var div = section.append("div");

div.selectAll("p")
    .data(points)
  .enter().append("p")
    .attr("style", function(d) { return 'left: '+d[0]+'px; top: '+d[1]+'px;' })
    .text('hi');

section.call(d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
        .on("zoom", zoomed));

function zoomed() {
  div.attr("style", `transform: translate(${d3.event.transform.x}px, ${d3.event.transform.y}px) scale(${d3.event.transform.k})`);
  div.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

function phyllotaxis(radius) {
  var theta = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
  return function(i) {
    var r = radius * Math.sqrt(i), a = theta * i;
    return [
      960 / 2 + r * Math.cos(a),
      500 / 2 + r * Math.sin(a)
    ];
  };
}
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tylergraf/pen/dOVREj) showing the issue.

**Issue:**
Notice that pan works great, but the zoom center point is off. It should zoom in centered on wherever your mouse is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really needed that `<div>`s and `<p>`s instead of `<g>`s and `<circle>`s;

Your translate coefficients are a bit off.

Changing your

```
function zoomed() {
  g.attr("style", `transform: translate(${d3.event.transform.x}px, ${d3.event.transform.y}px) scale(${d3.event.transform.k})`);
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

to

```
function zoomed() {
  g.attr("style", `transform: translate(${d3.event.transform.x-480}px, ${d3.event.transform.y}px) scale(${d3.event.transform.k})`);
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

will "solve" your issue I think.

Here's the updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBoPVx

Comment: Where does the `480` come from?

Comment: @TylerGraf width/2

Comment: thanks, that fixed it. Do you know why the coefficients are off?

Comment: @TylerGraf To be honest I couldn't figure it out yet but If you take a look at the elements your `div` is not centered in the `section`. That's where I come up with the "center" idea.